# Basic SQL/PHP (newbie) - what is the syntax to get the ' ID ' for a specific ' USER ' i.e

Tags: php, sql

The question is, I have an ID, username and a password for each user.

What is the syntax to get the ID based on a specific username and password.

I have this code but it doesn't seem to work :S

```
$dbusername=$row['user']; //php
$dbpassword=$row['password']; //php

$userID  = mysql_query("SELECT [$dbusername], [$dbpassword]' FROM users WHERE ID = $_GET[id]");

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastactivity = ".time()." WHERE ID = ".$userID);
```

Comment: I think you have things a bit backwards here.  If you have the username and password in php variables named $username and $password and are looking to use them to get the id from the database the select would be something like: SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'

Comment: Check out the documentation for the mysqli extension at php.net, plenty of good examples there

Comment: Thanks everyone. Ok so I have changed it.

This is my new code to update the ' lastactive ' column for the respective user but it still isn't updating the lastactive. The datatype for lastactive is Time so it should slot right in, what am I doing wrong?


    $userID  = mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$dbusername' AND password = '$dbpassword' ");
    mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET lastactivity = ".time()." WHERE ID = ".$userID);

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query with a SELECT statement returns a resource type, not the value you expect to have it. You need to use more commands there. Please check the documentation. It has several examples.

**NEVER** use mysql_* functions, always use **PDO** or *mysqli*.

Example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query doesn't return columns from the database.  It returns a query object.  You must then fetch rows from the database based on the query object.  Please read the mysql documentation carefully.  Better still, stop using mysql and use mysqli instead.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php